# Make LinkToSQL connection string editable post-compile in C#

Tags: linq-to-xml, connection-string

I have a project which uses LinqToSQL to query a database, but I don't know how to get the connection string from a file that I can edit after compilation. What is the correct way to do this?

I have a file called CleansingData built by the MSLinqToSQLGenerator and looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Database Name="MyDBApp" Class="DataClasses1DataContext" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/linqtosql/dbml/2007">
<Connection Mode="AppSettings" ConnectionString="Data Source=MyServer\MyDB;Initial Catalog=MyCatalog;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=MyUser" SettingsObjectName="CleansingDataReference.Properties.Settings" SettingsPropertyName="NetVisConnectionString" Provider="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<Table Name="dbo.CleansedData" Member="CleansedDatas">
<Type Name="CleansedData">
  <Column Name="CleansedDataID" Type="System.Guid" DbType="UniqueIdentifier NOT NULL" IsPrimaryKey="true" CanBeNull="false" />
  <Column Name="CleansedOperationID" Type="System.Guid" DbType="UniqueIdentifier" CanBeNull="true" />
```

I also have a Settings file with a ConnectionString setting with the value

```
Data Source=MyServer\MyDB;Initial Catalog=MyCatalog;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=MyUser;Password=MyAdmin
```

and an app.config looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="CleansingDataReference.Properties.Settings.NetVisConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=MyServer\MyDB;Initial Catalog=MyCatalog;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=MyUser;Password=MyPassword"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/></startup></configuration>
```

So I have ended up with the connection string in places! The only place I can change the connection string after compiling is the app.config but that does not actually get used by the application. The only way I have to point the application at a different database server is to alter the connection string in the Settings file and re-compile. This is obviously not right!

So how do I change this project so I can edit the connection string post-compile. Also, how do I avoid having the pasword in plain-text?

Sorry for the newbie questions!

--- Alistair.

Answer (score 0):

You should alter "yourapp.exe.config" file after compile and deploy, there is no app.config file in bin\Debug or bin\Release folder. 
This way you can use your datacontext's parameterless constructor.

```
    using (var ctx = new DataClasses1DataContext())
    {
    }
```

In addition to this you can use other contructors to pass in a connection string or connection, and can store and encrypt your connection string in any file as you like.

```
    // load from encrypted file or whatever
    string connstring = "???";
    using (var ctx = new DataClasses1DataContext(connstring))
    {
    }
```